# Auto populate data in pdfs

Tags: pdf, populate

I am developing a Java Desktop Application for Windows 7.

I want to auto-populate data into pdf file with specific format. For instance, if I select a particular product in the application then click on "Generate Report" button, it should fill the respective space in the pdf with the selected product.

Would like to understand different ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching on the topic found useful utilities like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) and [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). iText not free for commercial use whereas pdfbox is opensource project from Apache.